# Purchase Token data is same after i cancelled the subscription in Flutter

Tags: flutter, subscription, flutter-in-app-purchase

Hi i am new to flutter and i have integrated Auto Renewal subscription in flutter using this dependency. https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inapp_purchase

I have done sandbox Yearly auto renewal subscription so it will auto renew at every 30 minutes a maximum of six times in sandbox and this works fine.

**Issue i am facing**
Subscribed **userA@gmail.com** at 1:00 PM so it will renews at every 30 minutes and i logout **userA@gmail.com** from my app and i logged in with **userB@gmail.com** and try to **Subscribe/Restore** i am getting the valid purchased token which actually associated with **userA@gmail.com**

Does the scenario will be same in Production mode or will it give error in production mode?

If production mode scenario is same as sandbox then how can i manage it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

On the package page, they say that you should disconnect the billing service once you're done with it, or it will keep running in the background.

I'm not sure exactly how the plugin works, but it's likely that even if you logout, the billing service keeps running with the previous user's session.

So, what you should do is call  `await FlutterInappPurchase.instance.endConnection;`
whenever you logout, and call `await FlutterInappPurchase.instance.initConnection;` again with the new user.

The part of the package docs where they talk about this:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your comment but i think this it to close the connection so that `StreamSubscription` stop the listeners. but let me try this and will update you wether it's working or not.

Comment: I tried this but the issue is same as i mention in question.